# Can't get values from radio button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button

By this web page i want to let the user create question so he can write the question with its options and specify the correct answer.
The problem is when i select the correct answer(radio button), i can't get the value of the radio button

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string sQsnDesc = "", sCorrectOptn = "", sOptns = "", stxtOption = "", sResult = "";

    sQsnDesc = txtQsnDesc.Text.ToString().Trim().Replace("\r\n", "<br>");

    if (btnSubmit.Text == "Submit")
    {
        sOptns = ddlOptions.SelectedValue.ToString().Trim();

        if (rbtnOpt1.Checked == true)
        {
            sCorrectOptn = "Option1";
        }
        else if (rbtnOpt2.Checked == true)
        {
            sCorrectOptn = "Option2";
        }
        else if (rbtnOpt3.Checked == true)
        {
            sCorrectOptn = "Option3";
        }
        else if (rbtnOpt4.Checked == true)
        {
            sCorrectOptn = "Option4";
        }
        else if (rbtnOpt5.Checked == true)
        {
            sCorrectOptn = "Option5";
        }

        sResult = SqlHelper.ExecuteNonQueryOutput(sCon, "PS_Quiz_QsnCreationMaster_Insert", sQsnDesc, sOptns, sCorrectOptn, txtMarks.Text, Session["LogInId"].ToString(), null);
```

And when i try to insert the data it says that it' can't insert null value

you can take a look to the code here
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2BDZn7hHcrwZG9SQnhKMG1rcE0
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2BDZn7hHcrwbUlZdmNxNzVWek0

**Sorry i can't insert the hole code, Actually it's my first time to post in this site.

Comment: Please add the proper tags for programming language (looks like C# but I don't like to guess) and UI framework (Winforms, ASP.NET?)

Comment: Your question is missing crucial info: what language and platform you're using.

Comment: Which programming language did you use? Please add an approviate tag to your post.

Comment: what is sCorrectOptn ? Is it a control or text property of a control?

Comment: you can take a look to the code here
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2BDZn7hHcrwZG9SQnhKMG1rcE0
https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B2BDZn7hHcrwbUlZdmNxNzVWek0

Comment: What do you mean "cant get the value of the radio button"? are all the `.Checked` returning false?

Comment: exactly, for example if i selected rbtnOpt2 it should give sCorrectOptn = "Option2" but actually i'm getting this error
http://www12.0zz0.com/2013/06/18/15/408883680.jpg

Answer (score 0):

Is this asp.net and do you need to use the .findcontrol method to check the properties (in this case .checked) of your radiobuttons?

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/486wc64h.aspx

Comment: Yes this is ASP.NET, i follow your link but i already use .findcontrol method